# How to fix "Prefix creation exited with error" in Wine at mac?

Tags: macos, wine

When I install a .exe application in WineBottler,it shows an error "Prefix creation exited with error"

There is the error log:

```
    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro15,2
      Processor Name: Intel Core i5
      Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 4
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 6 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 8 GB
      Boot ROM Version: 1037.0.52.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.10531.5.4,0)
      Activation Lock Status: Enabled
 ###BOTTLING### Create .app...
 ###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat 
 menus...
 /Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 143: 
 /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
 ### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.



 ###ERROR### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.
Task returned with status 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT (27.10.19) : It works also with Mojave but you still get a few errors. If you downgrade to High Sierra, it will work perfectly. Just be sure that you download the last STABLE Version of Wine (4.0.2) and also install winetricks.

I'm guessing you're using the last OS version (Catalina).
From what I've found so far, 32-bit program support is going away on the Mac with Catalina, and atm there is no viable solution for this issue.
RN, I'm facing the same issue.
Still, I've found some kind of a workaround. Install wine via brew, use a 64bit version of the .exe that you're trying to install, and run the following command:

```
wine64 <your_program.exe>
```

If that still doesn't work, try downgraiding to Mojave, since it's the last OS version that supports 32bit apps. (That's what I'm going to do in the next few days, and I'll come back with an update)

Hope it helps !