# Prefix creation exited with error in Wine at mac

Tags: macos, exe, wine

My Mac runs OS version (Catalina). I had the same issue as this post [How to fix "Prefix creation exited with error" in Wine at mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650926/how-to-fix-prefix-creation-exited-with-error-in-wine-at-mac)
But it's been closed to answer, I start this new question to show a great solution from Jacob Townsend's YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkQj0lZFz6I

One issue I had is I'm not able to location the c_drive folder come to the step at 4'01" in the video. I just locate my exe file in my original folder. It works just fine. Also my exe file is very small, I don't know if it will work for big exe file.